# Why does a class definition always produce the same bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode, disassembly, python-internals

Say I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

class A(object):
    pass
```

Now I disassemble it:

```
python -m dis test0.py 
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('A')
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (object)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x1004ebb30, file "test0.py", line 4>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS         
             19 STORE_NAME               1 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now I add some statements in the class definition:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

class A(object):
    print 'hello'
    1+1
    pass
```

And I disassemble again:

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('A')
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (object)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x1004ebb30, file "test0.py", line 4>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS         
             19 STORE_NAME               1 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

What don't the new statements appear in the new bytecode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The new statements are stored in *nested* bytecode. You can see in your disassembly that *another code object* is loaded:

```
      9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x1004ebb30, file "test0.py", line 4>)
```

You need to inspect *that* code object instead. That's because the class body is executed just like a function object, and the local namespace that call produces is then used to form the class members.

Demo:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def wrapper():
...     class A(object):
...         pass
... 
>>> dis.dis(wrapper)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object A at 0x104b99930, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS         
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(wrapper.__code__.co_consts[2])
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)

  3           6 LOAD_LOCALS         
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is the same setup as your first sample; the class body is accessed via the `wrapper.__code__.co_consts` tuple, which is what the `LOAD_CONST` byte code refers to; the index is given as `2`.

Now we can add a class body:

```
>>> def wrapper():
...     class A(object):
...         print 'hello'
...         1+1
...         pass
... 
>>> dis.dis(wrapper)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object A at 0x104b4adb0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS         
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(wrapper.__code__.co_consts[2])
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              9 PRINT_ITEM          
             10 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  4          11 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             14 POP_TOP             

  5          15 LOAD_LOCALS         
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now the class body appears; we can see the byte code that'll be executed when the class body is loaded.

Of note are the `LOAD_NAME` and `STORE_NAME` bytecodes executed for each class body; those retrieve the module name and store those as a new local name `__module__`, so that your class will end up with a `__module__` attribute once created.

The `LOAD_LOCALS` bytecode then gathers all the local names produced in this 'function' and returns that to the caller, so that the `BUILD_CLASS` bytecode can use that together with the `'A'` string and the `object` bases tuple (created with `BUILD_TUPLE`) can produce your new class object.

Comment: Sweet. Didn't know that. Interesting question and a nice answer. (+1)